# Einstein's gravity Lagrangian invariance under the change of differential structure

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, topology

I came across an [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9610009) claiming the appearance of singularities in the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ as a result of changing the differential structure:

I wonder what symmetry or current (in case there is a continuum infinity of non-diffeomorphic differential structures just like that of $\mathbb{R}^4$) can be derived by demanding invariance of the gravity action under the change of differential structure in 3+1 dimensional Lorentzian spacetimes.

Personally (not only) do not assume strong causality (but also assume the opposite), where the manifold topology matches the interval topology introduced by the Lorentzian distance, but any answer or comment, even assuming strong causality is of paramount importance.

Further more one might consider the breaking of such symmetry, spontaneously or explicitly if not anomalously at the quantum level.

Comment: Down vote without comment = unprofessional and irresponsabile